# Vue setTimeout filter issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to implement notification system in Vue,
I have Notifications component, where I store error messages to show.

```
    data(){
        return {
            alerts: {
                error: []
            }
        }
    }
```

On an event in root component, I push msg in error array then I loop through them in Notification template.

```
            <transition-group name="slide-fade">
                <Error v-for="(alert, index) in alerts.error" :key="index" :alert="alert" @removeError="removeError($event)"></Error>
            </transition-group>
```

in Error component I show this message along with the closing button.

**Issue is that I want this message to close itself after 3 seconds. **

This is my Error component:

```
<template>

    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        {{alert.msg}}
        <button ref="closeButton" type="button" class="close" @click.prevent="remove()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["alert"],
        methods: {
            remove(){
                this.$emit("removeError", this.$props.alert);
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.remove();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I emit event either on button click or after 3 seconds by setTimeout, event is caught back in Notification component, where I call method to filter this message from initial array:

```
        removeError(toRemove){
            this.alerts.error = this.alerts.error.filter(item => {
                return item !== toRemove;
            });
        }
```

So button and Timeout share the same method. The thing is - when I have multiple errors pushed in my array and I use button, everything works perfectly, but while waiting for timeout, only some of those messages are being filtered (like 2 or 3 out of 5), while others remain in the array.

**images of the result**

[freshly pushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyDjm.png)

[after waiting for the timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hMO4.png)

**EDIT**

the issue was made by key on Error component - Vue gets confused as key of the array gets recalculated when element is removed.

Only it created another problem, because Vue does not accept non-primitive keys, it has to be either string or number. But I do have only the message in my string, which is obviously not unique as I can have 2 messages that are the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably this part is failing because you are comparing complex objects: `return item !== toRemove`
Try to use some primitive id to remove the item correctly.

Comment: I tried comparing the msg variable itself and indexes from the array as well but result is unfortunetely the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking the problem is with your key on:

```
<Error v-for="(alert, index) in alerts.error" :key="index" :alert="alert" @removeError="removeError($event)"></Error>
```

Could you try changing the key so it's like this:

```
<Error v-for="(alert, index) in alerts.error" :key="alert" :alert="alert" @removeError="removeError($event)"></Error>
```

I think Vue is getting confused because the key will get recalculated when one gets removed.
I did make a quick fiddle to reproduce the problem which was fixed when using a key that wasn't the index.

```js
Vue.component('notification', {
  template: '#notification',
  props: ["error"],
  created() {
  console.log(`Removing ${this.error} in 3 secs`);
  setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(`Removing ${this.error} now`);
   this.$emit("remove", this.error);
  }, 3000);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    errors: []
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.errors.push("Test: " + this.errors.length);
    },
    remove(error) {
    console.log(error);
      this.errors.splice(this.errors.indexOf(error), 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type="text/x-template" id="notification">
<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <strong class="mr-auto">{{error}}</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" @click="$emit('remove', error)">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
  </div>
</div>
</script>

<div id="app">
<notification v-for="(error, index) in errors" :error="error" @remove="remove" :key="error"></notification>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You are indeed a genius, thank you very much! Only it created another problem, because Vue does not accept non-primitive keys, it has to be either string or number. But I do have only the message in my string, which is obviously not unique as I can have 2 messages that are the same :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh okay. It's a bit annoying but I would probably create a unique index when adding the error and then just reference that as the key.

Comment: You may find these posts on these useful [unique-key](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6235) and [maintaining state](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

Comment: Okay I created random key like so `Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)` and pushed it to the array along with the message, it seems alright. Thank you very much again for your help :)